# Laravel Lighthouse - How to update multiple models

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I'm trying to update multiple models with a directive, but the current @update directive does not support multiple ids. I would basically want the @delete directive (where you can use a list of ids). To update multiple models. I'm guessing I could create a custom directive, but it's alot of code there that I can't wrap my head around. I've tried to read the [docs](https://lighthouse-php.com/master/custom-directives/argument-directives.html) to understand how to create a custom directive, but I can't get it to work.

So the DeleteDirective.php got this:

```
/**
 * Bring a model in or out of existence.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model $model
 * @return void
 */
protected function modifyExistence(Model $model): void
{
    $model->delete();
}
```

And I would basically want this (for multiple ids):

```
    /**
    * Update a model to read true
    *
    * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model $model
    * @return void
    */
protected function updateRead(Model $model): void
{
    $model->update(['read' => true]);
}
```

By defining a mutation query like this:

```
type Mutation {
  updatePostsToRead(id: [ID!]!): [Post!]! @updateRead
}
```

And doing a query like this:

```
{
   mutation {
      updatePostsToRead(id: [6,8]) {
         id
         amount
      }
   }
}
```

Does anyone know how I would go by doing this? Or can point me in the right direction?

Comment: I have not used Lighthouse before, but are you able to make a normal query? Because you could do something like `Model::whereIn('id', [6,8,10, ...])->update(['read' => true])`

Comment: @DouwedeHaan Sorry but the problem is not with code related to Laravel. I just don't know how to run the code with the custom mutation.

Comment: don't you think that in this case you should have a method accepting an array? if it operates on one record then it won't magically start to work on sets by changing mutation shape alone

Comment: @xadm The method is being run for every model...

Comment: What? I don't understand.

Comment: sorry, not this case, I didn't used Lighthouse ... you're probably searching for https://lighthouse-php.com/master/concepts/arg-resolvers.html#solution - last section (iteration over args)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a way to do it without creating a custom directive. Just made a custom mutation with `php artisan lighthouse:mutation updatePostsToRead`.

updatePostsToRead.php:

```
class updatePostsToRead
{
    /**
     * Return a value for the field.
     *
     * @param  null  $rootValue Usually contains the result returned from the parent field. In this case, it is always `null`.
     * @param  mixed[]  $args The arguments that were passed into the field.
     * @param  \Nuwave\Lighthouse\Support\Contracts\GraphQLContext  $context Arbitrary data that is shared between all fields of a single query.
     * @param  \GraphQL\Type\Definition\ResolveInfo  $resolveInfo Information about the query itself, such as the execution state, the field name, path to the field from the root, and more.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __invoke(
        $rootValue,
        array $args,
        GraphQLContext $context,
        ResolveInfo $resolveInfo
    ) {
        // TODO implement the resolver
        \DB::table('posts')
            ->whereIn('id', $args["ids"])
            ->update(['read' => true]);

        $posts = Post::whereIn('id', $args["ids"])->get();

        return $posts;
    }
}
```

Schema:

```
type Mutation {
    updatePostsToRead(ids: [ID]): [Post]
}
```

Query on client:

```
mutation{
  updatePostsToRead(ids: [2,6,8]) {
    id
    description
    read
  }
}
```